# Restrict access to child entities based on parent entity restrictions

Tags: rest, playframework-2.0

I've stumbled across an inconvenience of getting access to child entities in my application. For example I have the following entity structure in my App: 
**Company**->**Portfolio**->**Project**->**Project Stage**. There is also a **User** entity nested under **Company** entity witch has ManyToMany relation to **Portfolio**.

Whenever I try to access any child entity (e.g. **Project Stage**) I have to go all the way up to the **Portfolio** entity and check if it has a relation to the current **User** entity. So in a child entity's controller I have to use the following chain:

```
List<User> users = projectStage.getProject().getPortfolio().getUsers();
for (User user : users) {
    if(user.equals(currentAuthorizedUser)) {
        // allow access to child entity
        // break;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to automate this process so I don't need to repeat the same set of checks for each child entity in the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstable, you can make `ProjectStage` and `Project` implement an interface with one method

```
void checkAccess(User user) throw ForbiddenAccessException;
```

Each class must implement the check as you defined it in your code above.

Then, you can use [action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition) in your controller.

1. Create an action `CheckAccessAction` that extends `play.mvc.Action.Simple`
2. Before each method that needs the access check like `loadProjectStage()`, `deleteProject()`, `updateProject()`... add `@With(CheckAccessAction.class)`
3. In the `call` method of the action composition, you can do your check regarding the type of object that you're trying to access (if you can have the `currentAuthorizedUser` in the request)

You can define the `@With(CheckAccessAction.class)` at controller level if all the methods need it.